# Compass mixin transition

Tags: gruntjs, transition, mixins, compass

I just setup a project today using Grunt and Compass. I just tried to use the mixin transition and I am getting an error:

Error: Mixin transition is missing argument $time.

My SCSS code is below:

```
.five {
    .portfolio-tabs {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        li {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 25%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            a {
                border: 6px solid #f3f5f7;
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                min-height: 100px;
                @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
            } // a
            a.active, a:hover {
                border-color: #e1603a;
            } // a.active, a:hover
            img {
                margin: 0 auto;
            } // img
        } // li
    } // .portfolio-tabs
} // .five
```

I have tried other compass mixins and they seem to work fine. Is there an error in my SCSS that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation for a `transition` mixin. It seems like what you're looking for is to do this

```
@include transition-property(all);
@include transition-duration(0.5s);
@include transition-timing-function(ease);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. The problem was that the mixin was missing a comma to separate each argument.

Change this:

```
@include transition(all 0.5s ease);
```

To this:

```
@include transition(all, 0.5s, ease);
```